# How to add text to an image in php and return the image to browser

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using following code to create captcha image:

create function code:

```
public function create(){
    $this->image=imagecreatetruecolor($this->width,$this->height);
    
    for($i=0,$x=5;$i<$this->length;$i++,$x+=20){
        $angel=[mt_rand(3,35),mt_rand(350,360)];
        $y=mt_rand(30,35);
        $textColor=imagecolorallocate($this->image, rand(0, 255), rand(0, 255), rand(0, 255));
        imagettftext($this->image, $this->fontSize, $angel[mt_rand(0,1)], $x, $y, $textColor, $font, $characters[$i]);
    }

    return response(imagepng($this->image), 200, ["Content-type" => "image/png"]);
}
```

controller file:

```
public function getCaptcha(){
    if (ob_get_contents()) {
        ob_clean();
    }
    return $captcha->create();
}
```

sometimes it shows error :

> The byte stream was erroneous according to the character encoding that
> was declared. The character encoding declaration may be incorrect.
> [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axlFr.png)

[no error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otVms.png)

Comment: You said **sometimes** it shows error, can you elaborate ? (under what conditions it will show error, and under what conditions it will not ?, preferably give us minimal reproducible examples)

Comment: It happens randomly @Ken Lee

Comment: It says `Type: html` in your screenshot when you get the error, so something must have gone wrong before it even gets to the part where the `Content-type: image/png` header gets send. That your `getCaptcha` method needs to clear possible output buffer contents first, might indicate that you are calling this from some context where part of the process of assembling a HTML response has already happened at this point?

Comment: I added ob_start() at the beginning of controller and it solved the problem. But if there is an output before returning image from controller to browser how can I get it. @CBroe

Comment: Why would you _want_ to get it? You can not respond with an image _and_ other data at the same time.

Comment: I want to find the source of this output to solve it. @CBroe

Comment: Well you know about `ob_get_contents` already, no?

Comment: yes, But it returns empty string always. ob_start();
   var_dump(ob_get_contents()); // string(0) "" @CBroe

Comment: Maybe there was no actual output, and only the wrong content-type was triggered.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to find out what is happening? @CBroe